# Kentico Media Library search feature not searching sub folders of selected folder

Tags: kentico

Is there any way for Kentico Media Library application to search the sub folders of selected folder?

[image: media library application]

Files copied from FTP need to be "imported" into Kentico. If they were separated by folders/sub folders, you have to go to every single folder and "import" *that* folder's files.

I should not have to use [Kentico API](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/import-media-file) to do this simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid but the search is looking into the current folder only. You can send a request to productmanagement@kentico.com as a feature request.
For the import - I see your point but there could be also the opposite need - what if someone wants to import only certain files from certain folder(s). It is the same as if you would upload the files through the UI - you need to do it per folder. But I hear what you are saying  maybe there could be some setting for this. Again, you can send the feature request directly to the product managers.